How to add extension written by self When Druid deploy on k8s By image
I create a druid instance on k8s through druid image on company's repository. Now I write a new instance--oracle-metadata-storage to connect oracles as metadata storage. Because we use image to deploy druid, so I can't add the individual extension to the source code folder. Can anyone provide suggestion on how to add extension to image?
